# C++ Errors: LNK2001 and LNK1120

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I realize this is kind of an incomplete question, but I'm a student not thoroughly versed in debugging yet. When I try to compile I get the following output:

```
------ Build started: Project: p05Inheritance, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
employee.cpp
employee.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class CE::Company CE::Employee::company" (?company@Employee@CE@@0VCompany@2@A)
c:\documents and settings\km\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\p05Inheritance\Debug\p05Inheritance.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Does anyone know how I can go about resolving this? Thanks in advance, and let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: add the missing decl for `CE::Company CE::Employee::company` to the source file that holds the implementation of `class CE::Company CE::Employee`, though i suspect judging by the names alone it isn't supposed to be static in the first place. See the section on static class member variables and how they are used [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/). It is a ways down. Look for "Static Members"

Comment: Declaring Employee::company did it. As far as whether or not a static variable is appropriate, the header with definitions was given to be used as-is, and I'm just supposed to implement them in a .cpp file. Whether or not a static variable was necessary, I needed to use it. Thanks a lot, though.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that CE::Employee::company is not defined anywhere for the linker to find.  I suggest you give a little more info in your snippet ie the class in question for us to help you more precisely.